# Is the underlined AS a preposition or an adverb?

Tags: grammar

> Yogurt was rated **AS** less sweet than when eaten with heavier or larger spoons.

Is the underlined AS a preposition or an adverb?  Could you help me clarify it?   Thank you always.

Comment: **As** can be seen as an adverb because it introduces the second term of a comparative.

Comment: @LucianSava  yes, agreed.  Simpler example:  *Her hair was **as** soft **as** silk.*